# OpenGL Draw Rectangle At Given Depth

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, depth-testing

Currently, I have `GL_DEPTH_TEST` enabled and use it for textures. However, I'd like to draw a untextured rectangle with a certain depth/z value.

```
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glColor3f(colour.x, colour.y, colour.z);
glRects((short) rect.x, (short) rect.y, (short) rect.z, (short) rect.w);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

The code above draws the square. How do I set a Z or depth value for the square so that depth testing works with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `glRect` family of functions always draw with `z` implicitely at 0. So you have two options:

1. Set up same transformation which puts the `z=0` plane to where you like it.
2. Don't use `glRect` at all and just draw a rectangle using 4 vertices at the `z` coordinate of your liking.

You should be aware that *every* line in the code you pasted is relying on *deprecated* OpenGL functionality and `glRect` itself is a rather obscure function even for deprecated code.

Comment: How would one go about drawing a rectangle the _best_ way? (I am currently using VBOs for textures.)

Comment: VBOs are not for textures. They are for vertex data, as the _V_ in VBO explicitely states. I really don't know what you mean by that. But you should be using VBOs for any geometry data in the GL, as this is the only non-deprecated path to specify vertex attributes.

Comment: Yeah, one VBO for destination position and one for texture position in the sprite sheet. Thanks for the answer!